# Multidimensional, dynamic array in struct, size defined by int within the same struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc

I'm trying to make a game that uses a 2D array as the basis for its level. However, its size needs to be able to vary from level to level.
After a bit of research, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763343/setting-the-size-of-an-array-inside-a-struct-with-a-value-of-another-value-withi) that seems to have had the same problem as me. I've tried applying it as best I could:

```
 typedef struct level{

    /*other stuff*/
    int Size;
    int Arr[0][0];

}level;

level InitLevel(int S){
struct level* N = malloc(sizeof(level)+S*S*sizeof(int));
N->Size=S;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<S;i++){
    for(j=0;j<S;j++){
    N->Arr[i][j]=0;
    }
}
return *N;
}
```

Which compiled fine, so that's that. Problem is, once in the main, that looks about like this:

```
int main(){
    level myLevel = InitLevel(10);
    printf("%i \n",myLevel.Size);
    printf("%i \n",myLevel.Arr[5][5]);
}
```

While myLevel.Size returns the correct value, turns out the array's values were not correctly setup to 0, instead returning what appears to be either gibberish or memory adresses.

I am not sure of what I did wrong, but I hope I'm not too far off the solution? Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `int Arr[0][0];` stop right here. Delete this line. Arrays in C don't work this way. What in the linked question makes you believe you can do this?

Comment: `N = malloc(...); return *N`; dynamic allocations in C don't quite work this way either.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work; you seem to be expecting the compiler to just magically pick up on the fact that the `Arr` member's size is controlled by the member before it. That's not said anywhere in the code (because it's not possible to say), so how could it?

Clearly this:

```
N->Arr[i][j] = 0;
```

is going to have to compute an actual memory location in which to store 0, and to do so it needs two things:

- The size of one "row" of the array
- The size of one "element" of the array

the latter is well-known (it's `int`), but the former is `0`. For a 1-dimensional array, the first point above disappears, which is why indexing works since it's just using the well-known element size.

You need to do the address-calculation yourself, and drop the "magic" 0-size idea:

```
typedef struct level {
    /*other stuff*/
    int Size;
    int *Arr; // Size x Size 2D array.
}level;
```

Then do the access like so:

```
N->arr[i * S + j] = 0;
```

Of course, this also means `level` is not a value-type, since the `Arr` is not contained inside it. You can make it contained in terms of heap allocations, but you still can't just assign it around since the memory needed for `Arr` won't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot return by value a dynamically allocated struct. If you try, your struct will be sliced, meaning that you will only copy the first element of `Arr`, and will have a memory leak because the allocated memory will never be freed: you must return a pointer and release is later.

You have to ways to process your dynamic 2D array. One was proposed by @unwind and consist of a 1D array with explicit index computation. It it very efficient, but unfortunately do not allow you to use the 2D idiomatic `[i][j]`.

The alternate way is to use an array of pointers. You allocate the array itself of `Size`*`Size` ints **and** an array of `Size` pointers, each pointing the the beginning of the row. It is probably less efficient because it uses an array of pointer and an additional indirection instead of a direct index but you can use the idiomatic 2D access. If you can be sure that the alignment requirement of a pointer is greater or equal to the one of an int (*), you can do:

```
 typedef struct level{
    /*other stuff*/
    int Size;
    int **Arr;
}level;
level* InitLevel(int S){
    struct level* N = malloc(sizeof(level)+S*sizeof(int *) + S*S*sizeof(int));
    N->Size=S;
    int i,j;
    int *arr = (void *) N->Arr[Size]; // immediately after the array of pointers
    for(i=0;i<S;i++){
        N->Arr[i] = arr + i *Size;
        for(j=0;j<S;j++){
            N->Arr[i][j]=0;           // correct access
        }
    }
    return N;
}
```

Your main becomes:

```
int main(){
    level* myLevel = InitLevel(10);
    printf("%i \n",myLevel->Size);
    printf("%i \n",myLevel->Arr[5][5]);
    free(myLevel);
    return(0);
}
```

---

(*) Normally, you should allocate separately an array for the pointers and an array for the integers. But if the alignement requirement is stricter of same for a pointer to int than for an int, you can use the storage starting immediately after the array of pointer to store an array of ints.